# Javascript -- Recursion flatten without predefined flat method. Where exactly have I gotten lost?

Tags: javascript, arrays

*The Error is:*
** RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at flatten (/home/runner/TornPreciousBlock/index.js:1:17) at flatten (/home/runner/TornPreciousBlock/index.js:12:3)**

```js
const flatten = (arr) => {
  let flattenedArr = [];
  const flattening = (flattenedArr) => {
    for (let i of subElement) {
      if (Array.isArray(i)) {
        flattening(i);
        continue;
      }
      flattenedArr.push(i);
    }
  }
  flatten(arr);
  return flattenedArr;
}
flatten([1, [32],
  [3],
  [3, 5, [4]]
])
```

Comment: You unconditionally call `flatten(arr)` inside the definition of `flatten`. Maybe you meant to call `flattening(arr)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra function inside `flatten` function that you don't need and you initialised `flattenedArr` inside the function block, which is not a good idea because in each recursion you will be resetting `flattenedArr`

```js
let flattenedArr = [];
const flatten = (arr) => { //pass the array
  for (let i of arr) {  // get element of the array 
    if (Array.isArray(i)) { // check if element is of type array
      flatten(i);              // call same function again (recursion)
    } else flattenedArr.push(i);  // else push to flattenedArr
  }
  return flattenedArr;       // return flattenedArr
};
console.log(flatten([1, [32], [3], [3, 5, [4]]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you want to flatten an array is `reduce` and you can nest calls to it if you have an array of arrays. It is a standard JS function.  Though it looks like you should `map` then `reduce` based on your code example.

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```